# C null terminated strings in HP OpenVMS Pascal

Tags: c, string, char, pascal

I have a rather simple Pascal program, that is to call some C functions I have written.

My C code:

```
void connect_default(int* errorcode)
{
    // Connects the default user and places any error code in errorcode
}

void connect(char user[129], char password[129], int* errorcode)
{
    // Connects the given user and places any error code in errorcode
}
```

I'm trying to call these two functions in my Pascal application. This works fine:

```
program pascaltest(INPUT, OUTPUT);
procedure connect_default(var errorcode: integer); external;

var
errorcode : integer := 0;

begin
    connect_default(errorcode);
    if errorcode <> 0 then
        writeln('Failed to connect with error code ', errorcode);
end.
```

But I have a hard time finding out what data type to use in Pascal, that corresponds to a null terminated char array in C. A Pascal string does not seem to be it, because this passes nothing to the C function.

```
program pascaltest(INPUT, OUTPUT);
procedure connect(user : string, password : string, var errorcode: integer); external;

var
errorcode : integer := 0;

begin
    connect('MyUser', 'MyPassword', errorcode);
    if errorcode <> 0 then
        writeln('Failed to connect with error code ', errorcode);
end.
```

What datatype in Pascal corresponds to a null terminated C char array? My environment is a HP OpenVMS machine and not Free Pascal, meaning that I do not have access to the types pchar and ansistring that I have read about.

The C functions need to stay as general as possible and I cannot make any changes to them, creating custom structs (like what is described here [Declaring Pascal-style strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648947/declaring-pascal-style-strings-in-c)), as the C functions are already successfully called by similar programs written in C, Fortran and Cobol, where I managed to find the data types needed.

Comment: Respect for keeping the platform alive! :D

Comment: Wasn't Pascal string length stored to the first byte of the array? Couldn't you just move the whole string with `memmove` one byte left, and set the terminating `'\0'` to the end.

Comment: @JanneTuukkanen as described at the end of the post, I cannot make any changes to the C functions. Such a solution would probably work for Pascal, but then I would mess the C functions up for the calling Fortran and Cobol programs, that do not store the string length in the first byte.

Comment: Some pascal compilers can use the `PChar` type, which is a null terminated character array. `connect(PChar('MyUser'), ...`

Comment: It seems the `OpenVMS Pascal` has a `C_STR_T` type, which holds a null terminated array of char, and some helper functions, for example `MALLOC_C_STR()`, which allocates a `C_STR_T` from a string and returns a pointer to the structure.

Comment: @LURD: actually, a `PChar` is ***not*** a null terminated array at all. It is simply a pointer to a `Char`, but in C, that is how you point to the beginning or a zero terminated array of characters that form a string. So `PChar` is probably the binary equivalent of the C `char *`. But it depends on the version of Pascal whether that means it can be interpreted as a "C string".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, I don't know what you are getting at, but in Delphi, FreePascal and Turbo Pascal, a `PChar` type defines a null-terminated string.

Comment: @LURD: no, it doesn't. It is interpreted as such, and there are implicit conversions from `PChar` to `string`, but a `PChar` is still just a `^Char`. See ["PChars: no strings attached"](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pchars.html). It is certainly **not an array**, it just often **points** to a possibly zero terminated array. But that doesn't mean anything in the Pascal mentioned here anyway.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, you may twist and shout, but docs definitely says that it defines a null-terminated string.

Comment: @LURD: I am not "twisting" anything. It is a simple fact that a `PChar` **is not an array**. It is a **pointer** to a char that often happens to be the first one of a zero-terminated string (or, in many routines, pointing *into* one). But it is **never, in any way, an array**. Nor is it a string. It just often points to one. Docs merely say that a PChar (often) *defines* a zero-terminated string. Not that it **is** one.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, I did not say anything else than quote documentation. I can't see why you can't accept that. This is not Embas forum where you can twist everything for the sake of argumentation.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in official HP documentation, you Pascal version supports null-terminated strings: http://h41379.www4.hpe.com/doc/82final/6083/6083pro_005.html#null_strings

> 2.7 Null-Terminated Strings
>
> HP Pascal includes routines and a built-in type to better coexist with null-terminated strings in the C language.
>   The C_STR_T datatype is equivalent to:
>
> > C_STR_T = ^ ARRAY [0..0] OF CHAR;
>
> C_STR_T is a pointer to an ARRAY OF
>   CHARs. It does not allocate memory for any character data. C_STR_T
>   behaves like a normal pointer type in that you can assign NIL into it
>   and the optional pointer checking code will check for dereferencing of
>   a NIL pointer. The individual characters can be used by dereferencing
>   the pointer and using an array index.
>
> In these cases, no bounds
>   checking will be performed even if array bounds checking is enabled.
>   However, you cannot dereference a C_STR_T pointer without also
>   indexing a single character. If you want to access an entire
>   null-terminated string, see the PAS_STR function.

Then you can use that C-style strings as a read-only references or convert them into standalone Pascal strings via `PAS_STR` function: http://h41379.www4.hpe.com/doc/82final/6083/6083pro_016.html#pas_str_func

And `PAS_STRCPY` would do opposite thing right away:
http://h41379.www4.hpe.com/doc/82final/6083/6083pro_016.html#pas_strcpy

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction! Do you have any experience with it? I've been trying this now for a couple of hours, and I don't understand what C receives, but it's not right. If I call C_STR('MyUser'), place it in a C_STR_T variable and then send that to my C function, when I use printf in the C function on the parameter I received it prints the character "x".

Comment: I'm not with Pascal for many years and have no OpenVMS experience at all. Same time, I can say you need to use MALLOC_C_STR('MyUser') that would return proper C_STR_T result, see http://h41379.www4.hpe.com/doc/82final/6083/6083pro_015.html#malloc_func

Comment: I thought so too, so I tried both. Using MALLOC_C_STR instead does produce more than one character, but the characters are still wrong. I think I will have to investigate the options to my compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for now that does not affect my C code at all, but is not very dynamic. In my specific case, the user name and password are hard-coded.

I simply use a character array in Pascal, and set the characters one by one. It is however not a good solution in the general case, and I want to accept Yury Schkatula's answer as the correct one. That is the intended use. I cannot, however, since I never got it to work. I will update this thread if I find out why.

```
program pascaltest(INPUT, OUTPUT);

type username = array [0..6] of char;
type password = array [0..10] of char;

procedure connect(var user : username, var pass : password, var errorcode: integer); external;

var
errorcode : integer := 0;
user : username;
pass : password;

begin
   user[0] := 'M';
   user[1] := 'y';
   user[2] := 'U';
   user[3] := 's';
   user[4] := 'e';
   user[5] := 'r';
   user[6] := chr(0);

   pass[0] := 'M';
   pass[1] := 'y';
   pass[2] := 'P';
   pass[3] := 'a';
   pass[4] := 's';
   pass[5] := 's';
   pass[6] := 'w';
   pass[7] := 'o';
   pass[8] := 'r';
   pass[9] := 'd';
   pass[10] := chr(0);

   connect(user, pass, errorcode);
   if errorcode <> 0 then
      writeln('Failed to connect with error code ', errorcode);
end.
```

Comment: You should add a null character at the end of both arrays to conform to C null terminated strings.